# Showing NP, NP-Completeness, or NP-Hardness

Tags: algorithm, np

Is my understanding of the three categories correct?

To show a problem X is NP:

1. Show that X can be verified deterministically in polynomial time (Or
   X is solvable using a NTM)

To show a problem X is NP-Complete:

1. Show that X can be verified deterministically in polynomial time(Or
   X is solvable using a NTM)
2. Show that given a known NP-C problem L, L ≤p X
3. Show that given a known NP-C problem L, X ≤p L (Is this step
   necessary? If so, is this what differentiates a purely NP-Hard
   problem from a NP-C problem?)

To show a problem X is NP-Hard:

1. Show that given a known NP-C problem L, L ≤p X

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You almost got it.

Given a problem `X`, to show it is NPC, you don't need to show `X ≤p L`, for some NPC problem `L`.

In fact, this is guaranteed, since you already showed that `X` is in NP (in 1), and you know `L` is NP-Complete. By definition of NP-Complete, this means there is a polynomial time reduction from ALL problems in NP to `L`, including from `X`, so basically your step (3) in proving NPC is redundant.

---

A more elegant way to show the statements of what needs to be done to prove each property:

To show `X` is NP:

1. Show that X can be verified deterministically in polynomial time (Or X is solvable using a NTM)

To show `X` is NP-Hard:

1. Show that given a known NP-Hard problem L, L ≤p X

OR

2. Show that for any problem `L` in NP, L ≤p X (this is done only once actually, for SAT, and is the definition of NP-Hard).

To show a problem X is NP-Complete:

1. Show X is NP-Hard
2. Show X is in NP